# Countdown animation with rounded skiasharp rectangle in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have successfully created somewhat of a countdown with skiasharp. But my only issue is that I cannot get the correct shape i want the countdown to be in.

I can easily make a circle countdown, but it seems to be more complicated with a rectangle. When i want to do a circle countdown, the `AddArch` seems to work very well. If I use that with my skiasharp object and its size, it bends like a circle. So i need to do something else.

What i instead created my path with is this `path.AddRoundRect(new SKRect(1, 1, info.Width - 5, info.Height - 5), 30, 30, SKPathDirection.CounterClockwise);` And the sizing is good, but the problem here is that it does not create a new contour like it does for `AddArch`. So instead of cutting off the old "angle", in other words it just rotates around without removing parts of the border.

How would i solve this issue? Maybe to translate the `SKCanvas` could be the answer, but then i would know how mathematically calculate the translation from a arc shape to a full rounded rectangle.

I have a timer clicking on the side with updated `progressAngle` that keeps drawing the updated shape every second. `StartAngle` is 360.

This is my code:

```
    SKImageInfo _info;
    SKSurface _surface;
    SKCanvas _canvas;
    SKPaint _paint;

    protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        _info = args.Info;
        _surface = args.Surface;
        _canvas = _surface.Canvas;

        int size = Math.Min(_info.Width, _info.Height);
        int max = Math.Max(_info.Width, _info.Height);

        _canvas.Clear();
        _canvas.Save();

        DrawProgressBorder(_info, _canvas);
    }

 void DrawProgressBorder(SKImageInfo info, SKCanvas canvas)
    {
        int size = Math.Min(info.Width, info.Height);

        var shader = SKShader.CreateSweepGradient(
            new SKPoint(size / 2, size / 2),
            new[]
            {
                ProgressStartColor.ToSKColor(),
                ProgressEndColor.ToSKColor(),
                ProgressStartColor.ToSKColor()
            },
            new[]
            {
                StartAngle / 360,
                (StartAngle + progressAngle + 1) / 360,
                (StartAngle + progressAngle + 2) / 360
        });


        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            IsStroke = true,
            StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
            Shader = shader,
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            StrokeWidth = 15,
            IsAntialias = true
        };

        DrawBorder(_info, _canvas, paint, progressAngle);
    }


public void DrawBorder(SKImageInfo info, SKCanvas canvas, SKPaint paint, float angle)
    {
        int size = Math.Min(info.Width, info.Height);

        using (SKPath path = new SKPath())
        {
            path.AddRoundRect(new SKRect(1, 1, info.Width - 5, info.Height - 5), 30, 30, SKPathDirection.CounterClockwise);
            //path.AddArc(new SKRect(1, 1, info.Width - 5, info.Height - 5), StartAngle, angle);

            if (path != null && paint != null)
            {
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to indicate progress by drawing a rectangle?

Comment: @johnheaven Remove the border from an object. I have no fill. So it will be like a round rectangle removing its border until its fully removed.